# Given eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a matrix $A$, how to find its inverse and the limit of $A^nv$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that 
>   $$A\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$
>   $$A\begin{pmatrix}1\\ -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$
>   What is $A$? What is $\lim_{n\to \infty}A^nv$, where $v$ is an arbitrary vector $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}$, with $x, y > 0$? Justify your answer.

I know how to find $A$, all I had to do was augment the vectors above and solve for $A$...

$$A\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ -1 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2}\\ -1 & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 2 & -1\end{pmatrix} ^{-1}$$

and after finding the inverse and getting the product of the matrices above I get the following matrix :

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6}\\ \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{6}\end{pmatrix}$$

However, I am completely confused on obtaining a vector for $v$. Is $v$ supposed to be the eigenvectors for $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar matrix:
$$B=S^{-1}AS=\begin{pmatrix}1& \frac12 \\ 2&-\frac 12\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}\frac 23& \frac16 \\ \frac 13& \frac 56\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1& \frac12 \\ 2&-\frac 12\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&\frac 12\end{pmatrix}.$$
Hence:
$$A^n=SB^nS^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1& \frac12 \\ 2&-\frac 12\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1&0 \\ 0&\frac{1}{2^n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1& \frac12 \\ 2&-\frac 12\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}A^nv=\begin{pmatrix}\frac 13& \frac13 \\ \frac 23& \frac23\end{pmatrix}v.$$

Answer (score 1):

$v$ is not an eigenvector in general, but you may express it as a linear combination of two eigenvectors. (Actually, the problem already gives you all eigenvectors with eigenvalues!) Now try to investigate what happens.

Comment: So $v$ will look like this $v = a [1, 2] + b[1, -1]$... but is $a$ and $b$ both eigenvalues?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master Try to apply $A$ repeatedly. You will get $A^{n}v = a[1,2]+(b/2^{n})[1,-1]$. Now you'll see what happens as $n\to \infty$. (Also, you can find $a$ and $b$, so that compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} A^{n}$ explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you diagonalising the matrix, from there it’s gonna follow easily. And any term can be written out using eigenvalues.